# bootstrap centering thumbnail

Tags: html, css

I'm taking the Free Code Camp course thing and the first project is to create a tribute page to whoever. Mine is on J Dilla, my favorite hip hop producer. God rest his soul. Anyways I'm trying to use a bootstrap thumbnail around a picture of him, with the text/caption also inside the thumbnail. My problem is that it messes up the centering and aligns the thumbnail to the left and I have no idea how to fix it. Here's the relevant code:

```html
<style>
.cool-text {
  font-family: Lobster;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.image-centering {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;  
}
.vertical-centering {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.gray-background {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 20px 100px 20px 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.white-background {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 560px 10px 10px;
}

</style>

<div class="gray-background">
  <br>
  <h1 class="cool-text text-center">J Dilla</h1>

  <h2 class="text-center"><i>The one and only</i></h2>

  <br>
  <div class="span8 offset2">
    <div class="img-thumbnail thumbnails">
      <img class="image-centering" src="http://media.lessthan3.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/j-dilla-lessthan3.jpg" alt="The man himself."</img>
      <p class="text-center">Dilla working on something ill, I presume</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>

</div>
```

Also if there's anything glaringly terrible about my code, I'd love some input on how to reformat it. This is my first time asking a question on stack overflow so forgive me if this is the wrong way to do so.

Comment: Tried that.. didnt change anything. i thought text-center was a built-in class? besides, its not that text-center isnt working, its that by using the thumbnail class it unaligns the image/caption. thanks

Comment: If you are using pure html and css then no, .text-center class needs to be declared in css like any other class. Where is your .img-thumbnail class?

Comment: Your div with class name .gray-background is your parent div so try and give it the rule text-align: center; this should align you text. Aligning text in heading doesn't make much sense in your example.

Comment: that worked, thanks!

Comment: If you want to show your image a bit smaller, like a thumbnail, you can add some width and height properties to your .image-centering class like so: `width: 200px;` and `height: 120px;`. Set these properties to fit your needs.